# How to use jQuery plugins (jquery validation engine) with OpenUI5/SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I want use jquery validaton engine in SAPUI5. Please guide me, I have done following steps.

1. Added jquery library
2. Added jquery validation library and css.
3. Give a validate[required] class to input text field.
4. on button click called `$("#empform").validationEngine();` function.
5. But it is give me ***TypeError: $(...).validationEngine is not a function*** error.

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory: the DOM object referenced by `$("#empform")` does not have the `validationEngine()` function. What is this object, and are you sure it should have this function?

Comment: after following first three step validationEngine function should be available with form. But unfortunately it is not. That is why it is giving error.

Comment: Object `$("#empform")`, is this of type HTML `<form>`? The API documentation states "the plugin can only be instanciated on form elements"

Comment: yes it is form element

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is already part of the SAPUI5 distribution. So if you load SAPUI5 after including your custom jQuery + jQuery validation engine you will just end up with the plain jQuery version bundled with SAPUI5.

You can either load jQuery validation engine after SAPUI5 or use the no-jquery SAPUI5 variant as follows:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"            
        src="resources/sap-ui-core-nojQuery.js" 
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done following thing I have keep jquery reference from sapui5

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">    
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<local repository>/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<local repository>/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<local repository>/validationEngine.jquery.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks [cschuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842181/cschuff)